# Do I have to call the database in every single razor page model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

## Context

I'm working with ASP.NET core 2.1 & razor pages. I'm not using MVC so far, but I'm open to add it if neccessary.

I have the structure "Pages/MyPages/Login.cshtml". 
The ".../Login.cshtml" page have a model called ".../Login.cshtml.cs"

Now, I have this code in ".../Login.cshtml.cs":

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        // Set up private variables for database access and user/login managers
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;

        // Import database access and user/login managers
        public LoginModel(
            AppDbContext db,
            UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
        {
            _db = db;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
        ...
    }
```

## Problem

I have another razor page called "Pages/MyPages/CreateUser.cshtml", with its own model called ".../CreateUser.cshtml.cs", which is:

```
public class CreateUserModel : PageModel
    {
        // Set up private variables for database access and user/login managers
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;

        // Import database access and user/login managers
        public CreateUserModel(
            AppDbContext db,
            UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
        {
            _db = db;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Is exactly the same code as in Login.cshtml.cs, I want to know if there is a way to write this code once and apply it to every model I need.

## Didnt work

I tried to create a class called MyPageModel.cs which inherits from Page Model and set a constructor with the database, user and manager stuff:

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
    {
        protected AppDbContext _db;
        protected UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        protected SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;

        public MyPageModel(
           AppDbContext db,
           UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
           SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
        {
            _db = db;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
    }
```

Then Login.cshtml.cs and CreateUser.cs inherit from it:

```
public class LoginModel : MyPageModel
    {
    ...
    }
```

But it gives this error:

" There is no argument given that corresponds to the required forma parameter 'db' of 'MyPageModel.MyPageModel(AppDbContext, UserManager, SigInManager)' "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base page model has a constructor with parameters, but the inheriting classes aren't using that constructor.  They need to provide values to that constructor:

```
public class LoginModel : MyPageModel
{
    public LoginModel(AppDbContext db, UserManager<AppUser> userManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
        : base(db, userManager, signInManager) { }

    // the rest of the class implementation
}
```

They don't need their own constructor implementation, but do at least need to receive the constructor arguments needed and pass them along to the base class' constructor.